# Hosting Access Database

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-access

Attempting to host an Access database on a server running Windows Server 2012 R2. In the past I've always used services where database access was fairly preconfigured and am doing this one from scratch. I have IIS set up and working properly. I will be using ASP to access and edit the information in the database.

My ASP code and database have been tested and works on another setup, but am looking to transfer hosting locally. Aside from IIS what other software do I need to get this going?

Comment: `other software do I need to get this going` - A real DBMS?  Anyway, dpending on your code, you may need to setup an ODBC datasource.

Comment: I need help setting this up from scratch and haven't done this before. What's a good DBMS to use?

Comment: SQL Server, SQL Server Express, MySQL, Postgresql, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think better route would be to convert your M$ Access database to [SQL Server Express Edition | Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) (there are a lot of benefits to do that and really none to not too).